# How to do penetration testing on our Slack app hosted on Azure App Service?

Tags: slack, azure-appservice, penetration-testing

We have built an app using Slack SDK in slack app directory. It is hosted on Azure App Service. Since the API end point is exposed and can be accessed only within Slack, we are not sure how to perform penetration testing on it. We have to submit reports to our customers. How can we do that?

Comment: "can be accessed only within Slack" – what do you mean? Surely you can hit the endpoint URL with your browser and see what happens?

Comment: @SwapnilChowkekar could please tell which SDK you have used

Comment: @Sampath, we are using the following SDKs: 

"@slack/client": "^5.0.2"
"@slack/events-api": "^2.3.4"
"@slack/interactive-messages": "^1.7.1"
"@slack/web-api": "^5.15.0"

Comment: @AKX, yes you can hit the endpoint URL from browser, and it display 'App is running.' The problem is how do we perform the penetration testing on it.

API only processes the request that comes from Slack and ignores any other request.

Comment: How do you know it only processes Slack requests? What if someone were to masquerade as Slack? Etc.

Comment: @AKX, indeed you are right. The endpoint can be called from anywhere and it does execute the code. However, we use the '@slack/interactive-messages' as a middleware so when requests come from slack, it has all the necessary information that is needed to respond to the request, but we are not sure how can we pass all that parameters and do the penetration testing or which tool we can use for that.

I looked at some tools and they ask for OpenAPI. I am not sure what it is and how can I make my API as compatible with the OpenAPI standards so that I can run a Pen Test on it.

Comment: It's hard to help without further details or code. I would maybe consider hiring the services of an external pen-testing company; they would probably have a better perspective as to what to test for an app like yours.

Comment: Hi @AKX, we performed the Pen Testing using ZAP(https://www.zaproxy.org) and I think we are good for now I think. Thanks!!!

Comment: I wouldn't trust only the results of an automated tool, but whatever makes your customer happy.